# Using Allure report in java without any test framework

Tags: java, report, allure

Currently I'm looking into using Allure reporting with our testing engine with Selenium for automated tests. I've been using testNG with Allure, and the reports are as expected.

But I'm wondering if there's a way to use allure as a stand-alone tool, to generate the report without using any test framework like JUnit or TestNG. I've been using the Allure.getLifecycle() to create custom steps' result and detail like so:

```
StepResult stepResult = new StepResult()
  .withName(stepReport.getName());

getLifecycle().startStep(uuid, stepResult);
getLifecycle().updateStep(uuid, s -> s.setStart(stepReport.getStart()));

// some other stuff

getLifecycle().updateStep(uuid, s -> s.setStop(stepReport.getStop()));
getLifecycle().stopStep(uuid);
```

And I also see that there are functions like :

```
getLifecycle().startTestContainer(containerID ,new TestResultContainer().withUuid(containerID));
getLifecycle().startTestCase(testID1);
```

So I think that theorically I can create the whole custom test report, but calling the 2 functions above didn't give me any thing in the report, with or without using a test framework.

Have anyone tried to do this kind of thing with Allure that can help me with this?

Comment: Have you found any solution? 
So far I have found this class which has all methods which match with annotations. https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/blob/master/allure-java-commons/src/main/java/io/qameta/allure/Allure.java

Comment: I have somewhat found a solution, I recreated a custom Allure report based on how the report's json files that Allure uses. There is till room to improve on it, but I do now have a report generated at the end of the test using my framework and can be served with Allure. https://github.com/webrtc/KITE